# C# Audio File is played in a loop although it is stopped

Tags: naudio

I have an older implementation using NAudio 1.6 to play a ring tone signalling an incoming call in an application. As soon as the user acceptes the call, I stop the playback.

Basically the follwing is done:
        1. As soon as the I get an event that a call must be signalled, a timer is started
        2. Inside this timer `Play()` on the player
        3. When the timer starts again, a check is performed if the file is played by checking the `CurrentTime` property against the `TotalTime` propery of the `WaveStream`
        4. When the user accepts the call, `Stop()` is called on the player and also stop the timer

The point is, that we run sometimes in cases where the **playback is still repeated** although the timer is stopped and the Stop() was called on the player.

In the following link I read that the classes `BufferedWaveProvider` and     `WaveChannel32` which are used in the code are always padding the buffer with zero.

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/naudio-and-playbackstopped-problem.html

Is it possible that the non-stopping playback is due to usage of the classes `BufferedWaveProvider` and     `WaveChannel32`?

In NAudio 1.7 the `AudioFileReader` class is there. Is this class also padding with zeros? I did not find a property like `PadWithZeroes` in this class. Does it make to use `AudioFileReader` in this case of looped playback?

Below the code of the current implementation of the `TimerElapsed`

```
    void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                WaveStream stream = _audioStream as WaveStream;
                if (stream != null && stream.CurrentTime >= stream.TotalTime   )
                {
                    StartPlayback();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 //do some actions here
            }
        }
```

The following code creates the input stream:

```
    private WaveStream CreateWavInputStream(string path)
        {
            WaveStream readerStream = new WaveFileReader(path);
            if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
            {
                readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
                readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
            }

            if (readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample != 16)
            {
                var format = new  WaveFormat(readerStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 16,  readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels);
                readerStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(format, readerStream);
            }

            WaveChannel32 inputStream = new WaveChannel32(readerStream);
            return inputStream;
        }
```

Comment: You are AFAICT using a threaded timer - so it may be that the timer is active when you're stopping it and as such it will still be completed and would restart the stream. If that's the case you could solve it by using lock in order to "serialize" access to those shared ressources.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll give a try to find out if this is the case. Still I would like to understand if it makes sense to use the `AudioFileReader` instead fo the other mentioned classes.